# windows 10 empty context menu

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, windows-10

I am seeing this strange bug on windows 10 RS1 and RS3 desktop PC. After running for several hours, it starts to slow down and right click menu comes empty. Then apps stop launching and I have to reboot.

I did upgrade graphics and network drivers but this problem still persists.

I was seeing this problem on RS1 and I did clean RS3 install but I still see the same problem.

I've attached screen capture of empty menu.

I cannot confirm this but it is probably happening after installing Visual Studio 2017. After clean build, I installed VS 2017 (C++), python and cmake.

Thanks

[image]

**Update:**
I get the following error message and started seeing empty context menu.

```
---------------------------
WorkPace Fatal Error
---------------------------
Sat Jan 19 16:58:54 2019
Caught C++ exception "std::runtime_error"
Caught C exception: 
EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION; Address: 05A44B80; Continuable: true; Read from Address: 00000000

Please call support and provide the following file:

C:\Users\temp\AppData\Local\WPExcept.log
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

**Update 2**
I left system idle for 2 days and it looked fine. But I started using VS 2017 and started seeing the problem.

Comment: Some application is leaking GDI handles, would be my guess. In Task Manager on Details tab, right-click any column heading, Select Columns, and check `GDI objects`. See if there's a process using a lot of them.

Comment: thanks @IgorTandetnik I will check it out and add a comment here.